# Should I use a deque or vector to store huge deques in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, vector, deque

Imagine I have 40 huge deques each storing data of a user-defined type. 40 isn't that many, but the deques themselves are huge (hence why I've elected to use deques over vectors). My question is if I want a container for these 40 deques, should that container be a vector or a deque?

If I opt for a vector to contain my huge deques would that make the vector huge in memory, or do the elements of the vector simply point to the deques? If the containing vector becomes huge as a result of storing the 40 huge deques then will I need to use deques instead to avoid the contiguous memory-related problems I ran into when I initially opted to use deques for the user-defined type containers?

Example;

```
class myClass {
  // lots of data members resulting in large class object
}

int main(){

  std::deque<myClass> foo;

  for(int i=0, i<10000000, i++){

    myClass classObject;
    foo.push_back(classObject);

  }

}
```

We now have a deque with 1000000 elements containing our class objects. Imagine I create 40 of these deques.

Now if I want a container for these 40 deques should I do this;

```
std::vector< std::deque<myClass> > bar
```

Or should I do this;

```
std::deque< std::deque<myClass> > bar
```

Comment: Well, those options you presented cannot be exchanged arbitrarily. Please clarify more about what you actually need to achieve.

Comment: std::deque<myClass> tab[40]; ?

Comment: @willll I'd recommend using `std::array` over the built-in variant, but essentially, yes. The right idea.

Comment: Is the number of dequeues in this container constant?  Is the order constant?  Do you look them up by index or some other feature?

Comment: Is `sizeof(deque<myClass>` so large that making a vector of 40 of those is a problem?

Answer (score 4):

> do the elements of the vector simply point to the deques

To the question you asked: No.
To the question you meant: Yes.

In `vector<deque<T>>` the vector elements are the actual `deque` objects themselves, not pointers to them.  But `std::deque` objects are pretty thin, since they in turn have pointers to the double-ended data structure where the content of the deque resides.

Your 40 datasets will not be stored contiguous to each other in memory by using `vector<deque<T>>` (or even `vector<vector<T>>`) -- only when the inner container is allocation-free like `std::array` would the data of all containers be stored together.

If on the other hand you really want your vector elements to be pointers to `deque` objects, then you can use `vector<unique_ptr<deque<T>>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Containers store their actual data in external storage from the Free Store (heap). So there is no benefit to using a `std::deque` for storing just 40-ish *deques* because it will only be storing the *deques*' internal housekeeping data which is only a few bytes. So I would use a `std::vector` for this.

If the number is *exactly* `40` then I would conside a `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, as his holiness Stroustrup put it himself,

> I don't know your data structure, but I bet `std::vector` can beat it

meaning that usually you want linear structure and not something that might be a linked list or anything else underneath, because generally "rich" computation environments (read: PCs and such) are extremely good at optimizing linear access.

However, if it's true that each of these data-carrying class objects are large, and I mean "about as large as the CPU cache entries", then this won't make a huge difference. Use a deque if that's the right data structure (it's linear most of the time, anyway); also, you can also tell it to pre-allocate memory for 1000000 elements if you know it beforehand, by passing that number to the constructor.

Anyway, the memory structure you're using won't make a significant impact on how much memory you'll need, effectively. you'll need 40 * 10000000 elements. That's it. If that's more than the memory you have, you'll need to get more memory, or write a better algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider the options, as I see them they are:

- `std::vector<std::deque>`
- `std::vector<std::deque *>`
- `std::deque<std::deque>`
- `std::deque<std::deque *>`

The difference between `container<std::deque>` & `container<std::deque *>` is that all the members will be stored contiguously (deque is mostly but not entirely contiguous).
This means that with `container<std::deque>` accessing the contents will generally not cache miss but the actual data is stored in the object by pointer and will. whereas with `container<std::deque *>` the values in the container will cache miss and then again when you access the data.

Whether container should be a deque or a vector depends on whether you are likely to grow it back and whether you care about variable rate iteration. i.e. a vector is contiguous once set and so will not cache miss while iterating linearly over it, this isn't guaranteed for a deque, when it hops sub containers it will likely break the prefetch.

EDIT: I forgot to mention why you might prefer a cache miss over contiguousness, the answer is fragmentation. With huge data sets you put a lot of strain on the heap, increasing the chance an allocation can fail even though there is enough memory to store it because the memory is scattered across the heap, custom allocators are a potential best of both worlds option for fragmentation and cache misses.

Comment: I can't make any sense out of your answer. But remember that the data is actually stored in deques. Each one manages its own blocks of dynamically allocated memory. This affects cache misses and fragmentation.

Comment: stack overflow has eaten all my triangle brackets and made my answer incomprehensible, sorry, i'll fix it now.